# ISV Debugger exiting project initialization after failing to convert managed package to source format

Tags: isv

When attempting to initialize a new ISV Debugger session, I get all the way to step 7 before the shell exits with an error like:

```
ERROR running force:mdapi:convert:  An error was encountered processing path: /Users/nicholaszozaya/Salesforce/package_guidedselling/src/scripts/apex/debugger/RingDNA Full Sb/.sfdx/tools/isvdebuggermdapitmp/packages/TaskRay/lwc/trLtngOutDataFetcher/lwc/trLDSResetter/trLDSResetter.js
11:54:55.138 sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir .sfdx/tools/isvdebuggermdapitmp/packages/TaskRay --outputdir .sfdx/tools/installed-packages/TaskRay
```

This package is not mine, so I'd imagine my recourse from a metadata perspective is extremely limited.

Ideally, the package setup and conversion would just include my package - is there a way to ignore certain packages in the ISV Debugger project initialization process, or make the project configuration operation more resilient so it doesn't stop when it encounters such an error?